# Entity Framework: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multibyte code page

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity

I have a function which updates a field of table using entity framework.
This function retrieves a `User` record using `userid`, and updates the `UserState` field of a user to false.

My function works, but sometimes thrown this exception.

```
Entity Framework: No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multibyte code page.
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

My function:

```
 using (_DBEntities = new DBEntities())
            {
                var item = (from _key in _DBEntities.Users
                            where _key.UserID==userid
                            select _key).SingleOrDefault();

                    item.UserState=false;
                    _DBEntities.Users.ApplyChanges(item);
                    _DBEntities.SaveChanges();

            }
```

Comment: Can you post the exception, the message and type and line?

Comment: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=007a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. No mapping for the Unicode character exists in the target multi-byte code page. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070459)

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what's going on from the current info, but the exception suggests that you're encountering an error with the encoding/decoding of a Unicode character (no valid mapping can be found).

That probably hints at some problematic data within your Users table, if the exception is indeed occurring the within the above code block).

Character Encoding in the .Net Framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404377.aspx

Comment: I would recommend putting a breakpoint in your code where the exception is occurring, and trying to identify the condition that is causing your exception. If there's a particular `userid` that is causing your problem, inspect the record/data. This is assuming that the problem is indeed to do with data (which it may not be).